# PHP mysqli_multi_query large insert issue

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I've tried many ways in an attempt to insert a large amount of data parsed from a text file (200,000 lines of text gets parsed into the array in about 2 seconds on my server so I know that part isn't the issue). The mysqli_multi_query I'm using sends the queries in blocks of 5,000 (for some reason it refuses to do anything larger if I want to use multi_query more then once) OR if I split the text file down to 50,000ish rows I can insert them all at once in 2 seconds. If I do that then it refuses to run another query (I did read I need to do while (mysqli_more_results($db) && mysqli_next_result($db)); to clear the results out and I do have that for my 5,000 split one)

The 50,000 insert one runs in 2 seconds, the 5,000 insert one (of 50,000 rows) takes 40 seconds, I'm kind of tempted to just create a new mysqli connection in the foreach (for 50,000 inserts), but it doesn't always work...

I'd like some tips on how to make my function run faster since 40 seconds to insert all 50,000 takes forever when the file I'm reading from can contain sever hundred thousand possibly millions of lines

```
function log2db(){
$db = mysqli_connect(SQLHOST, SQLUSER, SQLPASS, SQLDB);
if($db){
    $qar = logparse("world2.chat", loglen());
    $query = "";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($qar['data'] as $q){
        $i++;
        $uid = $q['uid'];
        $type = $q['type'];
        $chldst = $q['chldst'];
        $time = $q['date'];
        $msg = $q['msg'];
        $query .= "insert into `messages` (`uid`, `type`, `chldst`, `time`, `message`) values ('$uid', '$type', '$chldst', '$time', '$msg');\n";
        if(!($i % 5000)){
            $qquery[] = $query;
            $query = "";
        }
    }
    $qquery[] = $query;
    foreach($qquery as $qq){
        $q = mysqli_multi_query($db, $qq);
        if($q){
            while (mysqli_more_results($db) && mysqli_next_result($db));
        } else {
            mysqli_error($db);
            return false;
        }
    }
    if($qar !== null){
        loglen($qar['filelen']);
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Is what I've come up with (always works but like I said is slow), any tips on how I can improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize the INSERT INTO query can insert multiple rows in a **single** query?

```
$parts  = array();

foreach($qar['data'] as $q){

    $uid    = $q['uid'];
    $type   = $q['type'];
    $chldst = $q['chldst'];
    $time   = $q['date'];
    $msg    = $q['msg'];

    $parts[] = "('$uid', '$type', '$chldst', '$time', '$msg')";
 }

$query  = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`uid`, `type`, `chldst`, `time`, `message`)";
$query .= "VALUES ".implode(', ', $parts);

mysqli_query($db, $query)
```

Comment: Really? I never did know that... I'll have to try it, I do think I've seen that mentioned before but never tried it...

Comment: Thank you very, very, very much! It now completes in about 4 seconds total (log parse and sql insert). I really can't thank you enough

Comment: Hey, although this posting is older than a year I'd like to call your attention that it contains a vulnerability for SQL injections. It would be better to use prepared statements or at least using $mysqli->real_escape_string() in order to sanitize user inputs.